# Simplifying recursive use of ifelse()

Tags: r

I am trying to create a numeric variable that represents the center of a binned variable. The bins are age by decades, e.g. "20-29" and in need to have 25 instead. Below is the R code I am using. I am looking for a simpler code. thanks.

```
dataMet_F$Age_bx <- ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "20-29", 25,
                              ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "30-39", 35,
                                     ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "40-49", 45,
                                            ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "50-59", 55,
                                                   ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "60-69", 65,
                                                          ifelse(dataMet_F$AgeBinned == "70-79", 75,
                                                                 NA))))))
```

Comment: You can use `case_when()`. Take a look at [the case_when() documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html). It's also easier if you provide sample data, for example by posting the output of `dput(dataMet_F)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on `'-'`, take average of two values and use `ceiling` so that values like 34.5 change to 35.

```
dataMet_F$Age_bx <- sapply(strsplit(dataMet_F$AgeBinned, '-'), function(x) 
                    ceiling(mean(as.numeric(x))))
dataMet_F

#  AgeBinned Age_bx
#1     30-39     35
#2     40-49     45
#3     60-69     65
#4     50-59     55
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
dataMet_F <- data.frame(AgeBinned = c("30-39", "40-49", "60-69", "50-59"))
```